# How do I log in to a system reserved through Beaker?

Tags: beaker-testing

I found the Reserve Workflow in Beaker, and used it to schedule a job. Beaker reserved a system for me and sent me an e-mail with the FQDN.

Now how do I log in?

(Based on a "question" asked by a frustrated Beaker user on 2014-03-01 in Bugzilla.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use SSH key authentication. You can add your SSH public key on the Preferences page (select Hello -> Preferences from the menu), then Beaker will add it to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` in all of your jobs. (You needed to do this before you submitted your reservation job. Beaker doesn't magically update your public SSH key on recipes that are already running.)

Otherwise you can log in as root using a password. Beaker will use the root password you set on the Preferences page (if you set one), otherwise there is a default Beaker-wide root password. You can find that on the Preferences page as well.